# for loop iteration over character values

Tags: r, for-loop, character

> I'm new to R and try to get used to for loops. I'm currently solving a couple of exercises to practice and I'm currently stuck at this one;

I have a vector

```
v <- sample(c("cat", "dog", "mouse"), 100, replace = TRUE);
```

Now the question is to create a for loop that iterates through all the values of 'v' printing how many dog values found up to that point. When getting to the fifth 'dog' value you should stop. (after the corresponding print). Use break.

To beginn with I'm not able to produce the first iteration where I produce the output like "1 n_dogs found". Furthermore, I'm not sure how to count the number of "dogs" found and break the loop after printing the fifth "dog" value. After a few tries I ended here (which does not give anything close to the output desired)

```
for (index in 1:length(v)){
  if (v[index] == "dog"){
    print(sprintf("%s n_dogs found", v[index]));
    break;
  } else {
 print(sprintf("%s n_dogs found", v[index]));
  }
}
```

I know this is very basic but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: thanks, updated the question

Comment: You also might want to set up some sort of `counter` variable that gets increased by 1 when you find a `"dog"`. Maybe put `counter <- 0` before the loop starts, and modify that value to go up by one every time you find a `"dog"` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
v <- sample(c("cat", "dog", "mouse"), 100, replace = TRUE)

counter <- 0

for (value in v) {
  if (value == "dog") {
    counter <- counter + 1
    print(sprintf("%s n_dogs found", counter))
  }
  if (counter == 5) {
      break
  }
}
```

You can use a simple counter. I have also replaced the traditional loop with for-each. You don't need to break, that will only count till the first appearance of `dog`. if you only need the final number, then increment the counter in the loop and simply print outside.

Comment: great, thanks. However, I want to break after the 5th value (after printing it). Can I add another if statement with (counter == 5) to do that? I tried 

```for (value in v){
  if (value == "dog"){
    print(sprintf("%s n_dogs found", counter));
    counter <- counter + 1
  }
  if (counter == 5);
  break; 
}
``` 
But that does not do the trick.

Comment: Yes, you can check my latest update. The value of `counter` is changed, please note that. Also, don't forget to accept/upvote the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try the code below, where the `for` loop is terminated once the fifth "dog" is found

```
ndog <- 0
for (x in v) {
  if (x == "dog") {
    ndog <- ndog + 1
    print(sprintf("%s n_dogs found", ndog));
  }
  if (ndog == 5) break
}
```